# reduce nodes in polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, vector

I have a shapefile with several contiguous polygons and I want to reduce their number of nodes.
I was thinking of deleting nodes based on the angle that results from the 2 segments on either side of the node; in particular deleting nodes which form angles of <180 and  >170º.
How could I do this in ArcMap?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the best solution is to use the Simplify Polygon tool of the Generalisation toolset! Check the link below for details.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/simplify-polygon.htm

Alternatively you can use Simplify Line Or Polygon tool of the Data Management toolset. Check the link below for details.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/simplify-line-or-polygon.htm

Have you tried any of those? I think the first one gives you more options and it is available in ArcGIS for Desktop Standard!

Comment: I've tried both of them, but I wanted some way to do the calculation based on the angles that make the 2 segments on each side of the node in order to have control of the nodes that are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Generalize tool in the editing toolbar. If you look at the tolerance parameter, you will find how it resolves your struggle with the almost linear features. However it does not guarantee that the adjacent polygons will be topologically consistent, which is another issue addressed in this SE.

Comment: Thanks but I need the adjacent polygons to be topologically consistent

Comment: You can always apply [Integrate](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm) tool to make them topologically correct. Have you tried any suggestions in the answers? If you have and any of them solved your problem, please mark it as answer.

Comment: I tried both answers but still don't solve my problem